# How to pass one Java object from one XPage to another

Tags: java, xpages, view-scope

In my Xpages application I want the user to make some choices what kind of product she/he is interest in and based upon the decisions direct the user to another Xpage.

The information from the first "pre-selection" XPage I want to send further to the second "product order" XPage.

The first page stores the information in a managed bean with scope length of a view.

I tried to implement the flashscope principle https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=flashscope-implementation-for-java-beans

but I wonder how I can implement this? Is there any example code available or am I searching in the wrong direction?

For example on the first xpage I have a button which has a simple action to open the second page.

On the second page I have an editbox:

```
<xp:inputText id="inpCustomerID" value="#{applicationBean.order.customer.custId}"/>
```

but this value remains empty when I navigate from the first page to the second (although I have set it in the first page)

Comment: Why don't you use the managed bean with session scope? The Java object would be available for your secondary product page then.

Comment: Hello Knut, I had this before in an application but then users had multiple tabs open in the browser and that created a lot of confusion / incorrect entries.

Comment: Maybe consider combining XPage 1 and 2 into one XPage? Or if you just need to pass a product id then use a URL query parameter

Comment: Passing the id (of a customer) will not be sufficient because the details for the customer is done via multiple calls to different resources. Would be insufficient to perform that action one more time while I have them already aggregated in a Java object. But passing them from one bean to another with a lifespan of viewScope is not possible you are saying?

Comment: To avoid session scopes to mix up, you can put the bean in sessionScope when clicking on the 'Goto Page 2' button. In the beforePageLoad of Page 2, copy the bean to the viewScope (of the new page) and remove it from the sessionScope.
Using this technique, the sessionScope remains clean.

Comment: Why not cache the customer object in map in the sessionscope or a sessionbean? with the customer id as key ?

Comment: Hi Umeli, as I answered to Knut the users tend to have the application open via multiple tabs so a sessionscope would cause probably incorrect results.

Comment: I like Per's first approach.  Demote XPage 1 and 2 to Custom Controls and then use a dynamicContent control for the staging.  This is easiest if you can stay on the same page.

Comment: @malin I meant to store the customer objects in a map<customerid,customer> in a sessionbean or sessionscope so you can pass just the customer id between the pages....